# Изменить DataFrame по условию

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть такой массив данных, необходимо в нем перед всеми названиями Comp вставлять вверх новую строчку пустую(кроме первого названия)

```
   Comp       E      F       G      H       I
0     A  70.000 80.000  88.000 95.000   5.000
1   NaN 162.000 50.000  55.000  6.000   4.000
2   NaN   8.000  8.000   4.000 33.000   2.000
3     B   8.000  9.000   5.000 44.000  -6.787
4   NaN   4.000  5.000   5.000  5.000  50.000
5   NaN  77.400  2.000   3.000  2.000  35.000
6     C  88.400 66.000   0.000 55.000 500.000
7   NaN  55.000  6.000 200.600  3.300   5.000
8   NaN  99.100 66.000   2.600  6.200   5.000
9     D   5.000 18.300   6.000 -3.100   8.000
10  NaN  77.400 53.000   3.000  0.000  12.611
11  NaN   4.000  4.000   4.000 52.000   5.000
```

т.е. должно получиться как то так

```
   Comp       E      F       G      H       I
0     A  70.000 80.000  88.000 95.000   5.000
1   NaN 162.000 50.000  55.000  6.000   4.000
2   NaN   8.000  8.000   4.000 33.000   2.000
3   NaN     nan    nan     nan    nan     nan
4     B   8.000  9.000   5.000 44.000  -6.787
5   NaN   4.000  5.000   5.000  5.000  50.000
6   NaN  77.400  2.000   3.000  2.000  35.000
7   NaN     nan    nan     nan    nan     nan
8     C  88.400 66.000   0.000 55.000 500.000
...
```

И так далее

Пустая строка нужна чтобы при переходе от одного значения Comp к другому и расчету изменения (дельты) не выходило ошибок. А первое значение дельты каждой новой Comp соответственно равнялось бы нулю или пропуску

Comment: Вы можете показать исходный DataFrame из которого вы получили данный в вопросе? Заменить NaN нулями можно гораздо проще...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import numpy as np

res = (df.groupby(df.Comp.ffill())
         .apply(lambda x: x.append(pd.Series([np.nan] * df.shape[1],
                                             index=df.columns),
                                   ignore_index=True))
         .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Результат:

```
In [125]: res
Out[125]:
   Comp       E      F       G      H       I
0     A  70.000 80.000  88.000 95.000   5.000
1   NaN 162.000 50.000  55.000  6.000   4.000
2   NaN   8.000  8.000   4.000 33.000   2.000
3   NaN     nan    nan     nan    nan     nan
4     B   8.000  9.000   5.000 44.000  -6.787
5   NaN   4.000  5.000   5.000  5.000  50.000
6   NaN  77.400  2.000   3.000  2.000  35.000
7   NaN     nan    nan     nan    nan     nan
8     C  88.400 66.000   0.000 55.000 500.000
9   NaN  55.000  6.000 200.600  3.300   5.000
10  NaN  99.100 66.000   2.600  6.200   5.000
11  NaN     nan    nan     nan    nan     nan
12    D   5.000 18.300   6.000 -3.100   8.000
13  NaN  77.400 53.000   3.000  0.000  12.611
14  NaN   4.000  4.000   4.000 52.000   5.000
15  NaN     nan    nan     nan    nan     nan
```

Comment: Выдает `UsageError: Line magic function `%paste` not found.`

Comment: Выдает `NameError: name 'np' is not defined`